# i have problem with my javascript on codeigniter, parse to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

i have some problem, i want to push my data to form html with javascript obj but it can't push with id

this is my javascript

```
{if {form_case} == ubah}
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data={data_by_id};


    for (var obj in data) 
    {
        alert(data[obj]);
        $("#" + obj).val(data[obj]);
    }

</script> {/if}
```

this my form html

```
<form class="form" form-case="{form_case}">

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Nama">Nama</label>
                                <input type="text" class=" riset form-control" id="nama_user" name="nama_user" placeholder="">
                                <div>
                                    <?php print form_error('nama_user', '<small class="text-danger">', '</small>') ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Username">Username</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username">
                                <div>
                                    <?php print form_error('username', '<small class="text-danger">', '</small>') ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Password">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
                                <div>
                                    <?php print form_error('password', '<small class="text-danger">', '</small>') ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="float-right">
                                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" name="simpan" data-link="{base_url}/{lvl_auth}/{base_class}/store">Simpan</button>
                                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" name="reset">Reset</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

this my result in inspect element
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30kzC.jpg)

then this ini my result on html it can't show the value in field
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YetwD.png)

Comment: shouldn't it be `{if {form_case} == 'ubah'}` instead of `{if {form_case} == ubah}`?

Comment: i'm using parser in code igniter, and if got from form-case="{form_case}"